# The vanishing of the $\bf B$s

Tags: sequences-and-series, bernoulli-numbers

Define $B_0=1$ and recursively $$\tag 1 \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom {n+1}k B_k=[n=0]$$

How can I prove $B_{2n+1}=0$ for $n\geqslant 1$ using this definition?

Note the above means that  $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom {n}k B_k=B_n+[n=1]$$

but of course we should use $(1)$ to recursively compute them.

Comment: What does $[n=1]$ mean there in $(2)$?

Comment: Expanding $f(z) = \frac{z}{e^z-1} = \sum \frac{B_n}{n!} z^n$ and noting $f(z) + \frac{z}{2}$ is even doesn't count?

Comment: @Kunnysan, $[P]$ is the Iverson bracket, $1$ if $P$ is true and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @DanielFischer Nope, sorry. I only want to use $(1)$ or $(2)$, or anything that derives from those. I guess one can prove that is the EGF of $B_n$ using $(2)$. If so, I'm all in.

Comment: Pardon me, comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have $(-1)^nB_n=B_n+[n=1]$. How is this true?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Kind of thought so. Although, you can call the numbers $C_n$ in the power series expansion, and verify that the $C_n$ obey the same recursion as the $B_n$, whence $C_n = B_n$. One could argue that follows the letter of the law ;)

Comment: @Kunnysan Because the odd Bernoulli numbers vanish (which we want to prove), and $B_1=-1/2$. Then $1/2=-1/2+1$ holds, and all the rest holds trivially, since $(-1)^{2n}=1$.

Comment: It seems to me that these conditions don't actually define $B_2$; in (1), for instance, we get $B_0+2B_1+B_2=B_2$, which is true no matter what $B_2$ you choose. Are the indices of summation off?

Comment: Right - and so $B_2$ can take any value.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson Ah. Let me correct this.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson I think now it should work.

Comment: The title sounds like it's about Colony Collapse Disorder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+1}{k}B_k=[n=0]\tag{1}
$$
Summing $(1)$ times $(-1)^n\binom{m}{n+1}$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
m
&=\sum_{n=0}^m\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^n\binom{m}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}B_k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{n=k+1}^m(-1)^{n-1}\binom{m}{n}\binom{n}{k}B_k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{n=k+1}^m(-1)^{n-1}\binom{m}{k}\binom{m-k}{n-k}B_k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(-1)^k\binom{m}{k}B_k\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Setting $m=n+1$ in $(2)$ and subtracting $(1)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
n+1-[n=0]
&=\sum_{k=0}^n((-1)^k-1)\binom{n+1}{k}B_k\\
&=-2\sum_{k=0}^{\large\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}\binom{n+1}{2k+1}B_{2k+1}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Subtracting the $k=0$ term from both sides and substituting $n\mapsto2n+1$ results in
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{2n+2}{2k+1}B_{2k+1}=0\tag{4}
$$
which inductively shows that $B_{2k+1}=0$ for $k\ge1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let. $n$ be an odd number: $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom {n+1}k B_k=0$$ gives us $n$ linear equations.

$$\begin{align}
  \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \binom{n+1}k{B_k} &=  - 1 \cr 
  \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \binom nk {B_k} &=  - 1 \cr 
  \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 2} \binom{n-1}k {B_k} &=  - 1 \cr 
   \cdots  &=  \cdots  \cr 
  \sum\limits_{k = 1}^2 \binom 3k {B_k} &=  - 1\cr
  \sum\limits_{k = 1}^1 \binom 2k {B_k} &=  - 1 \end{align} $$

**Corurtsy for the matrix formulation: Robjohn**

System these linear equation gives us,$$\textstyle
\begin{bmatrix}
\binom{n+1}{n}&\cdots&\binom{n+1}{3}&\binom{n+1}{2}&\binom{n+1}{1}\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&\cdots&\binom43&\binom42&\binom41\\
0&\cdots&0&\binom32&\binom31\\
0&\cdots&0&0&\binom21
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\vphantom{\binom11}B_n\\ \vdots\\ \vphantom{\binom11}B_3\\ \vphantom{\binom11}B_2\\ \vphantom{\binom11}B_1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\vphantom{\binom11}-1\\ \vdots\\ \vphantom{\binom11}-1\\ \vphantom{\binom11}-1\\ \vphantom{\binom11}-1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now if one applies Cramar's rule to solve $B_n$, will have $B_n=\frac{\det A_n}{\det D_n}$. $D_n$ is the above matrix. $A_n$ is same as $D_n$ with $1$'st column is $(-1, -1,...,-1)^t$. Just do elementary row operation, you will get $\det A_n =0$

I think that, $(1)$ would be easier to calculate $B_n$ as the determinant, however $(2)$ is also giving 'same type' matrix. If you just check, you would see that after killing $-1$ in first column automatically $A_n$ becomes an upper triangular matrix with one diagonal element $0$. So determinant vanishes.

Comment: Your question is edited, I am not sure whether I did all my calculation right. But this process should work with your edited question also.

Comment: Yes, let me edit my answer according to your question.

Comment: Of course, we can assume by induction that $B_{2k-1}=0$ for $k=2,3,\dots,n$ and then using your idea prove $B_{2n+1}=0$.

Comment: Are those the $n$ equations you intended?

Comment: I was just writing those. Yes, these are the equations.

Comment: I'm failing to see how this method would work. Could you make an example, say assume $B_3,B_5,B_7=0$ and show $B_9=0$?

Comment: I am getting $B_9=0$, but calculation is becoming too messy to generalize. But, I have a strong intuition that this process should work!

Comment: But I don't understand. All the equations after the first are just equalities that don't involve $B_n$.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Is there any problem with that? We may treat $\{B_i: i \ge 1 \}$ as unknown variables. And we are only interested to find $B_n$ ($n$ odd). And the claim is the determinant in numerator which only involves various $n-r \choose k-r$ will vanish.

Comment: $A_n(i,j)=-1$ for $j=1$;  $A_n(i,j)={n-i+2 \choose n-j+1}$ for $j>1, i\le j$ ;or $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Could you provide more details in the body of this answer? Specifically how to show the determinant is zero, and make the system explicit? It seems this works. If so, I'm more than happy to accept the answer, but I need to understand the solution fully! =)

Comment: @Kunnysan: is your system equivalent to
$$\textstyle
\begin{bmatrix}
\binom{n+1}{n}&\cdots&\binom{n+1}{3}&\binom{n+1}{2}&\binom{n+1}{1}\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&\cdots&\binom43&\binom42&\binom41\\
0&\cdots&0&\binom32&\binom31\\
0&\cdots&0&0&\binom21
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\vphantom{\binom11}B_n\\ \vdots\\ \vphantom{\binom11}B_3\\ \vphantom{\binom11}B_2\\ \vphantom{\binom11}B_1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\vphantom{\binom11}-1\\ \vdots\\ \vphantom{\binom11}-1\\ \vphantom{\binom11}-1\\ \vphantom{\binom11}-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Yeah that's true! It is.

Answer (score 0):

After RobJohn's solution there is no more answer needed; but I've seen now the source of the little understanding in my previous answer *(but which has several comments so I hesitate to retract/delete it; please leave a comment if you prefer that answer to be deleted)*.
Here is an improvement/correction for the matrix notation which I wanted to arrive at.

---

The recursive binomial identity (1) in the OP is  $$ \bf P^* \cdot \bf B = \bf I_0 $$ or in explicite matrix-notation
$$ \small \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\ 
 1 & 2 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\ 
 1 & 3 & 3 & . & . & . & . & . \\ 
 1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & . & . & . & . \\ 
 1 & 5 & 10 & 10 & 5 & . & . & . \\ 
 1 & 6 & 15 & 20 & 15 & 6 & . & . \\ 
 1 & 7 & 21 & 35 & 35 & 21 & 7 & . \\ 
 1 & 8 & 28 & 56 & 70 & 56 & 28 & 8
 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1\\b_1\\b_2\\b_3\\b_4\\b_5\\b_6\\b_7 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$ which can be thought to be continued to any dimension. Here the $b_k$ are unknowns to be determined and $b_0=1$ was given by definition. Because $\bf P^*$ is triangular and has nonzero diagonal elements it is invertible and there is a ***unique*** solution for $ \bf B$ where the property of being unique is part of the conjecture to be proved.
Now if we invert $ {\bf G} = {\bf P^*} ^{-1}$ we get
$$ {\bf G} =\small \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\ 
 -1/2 & 1/2 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\ 
 1/6 & -1/2 & 1/3 & . & . & . & . & . \\ 
 0 & 1/4 & -1/2 & 1/4 & . & . & . & . \\ 
 -1/30 & 0 & 1/3 & -1/2 & 1/5 & . & . & . \\ 
 0 & -1/12 & 0 & 5/12 & -1/2 & 1/6 & . & . \\ 
 1/42 & 0 & -1/6 & 0 & 1/2 & -1/2 & 1/7 & . \\ 
 0 & 1/12 & 0 & -7/24 & 0 & 7/12 & -1/2 & 1/8
 \end{bmatrix}$$ and by 
$$ {\bf B } = {\bf G } \cdot {\bf I}_0$$
our result for $ \bf B $ is the first column of $\bf G$ where indeed the entries at odd indexes $ \gt 2$ vanish (and being the unique solution this answers the question in part).

Well, this does not suffice as a proof; a complete proof must now show, that the entries at odd indexes $\gt 2$ do indeed vanish, but gives at least the heuristic insight from which then a proof could be derived.